# Excluding a single java file from indexing?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

There are 'demo', 'full' flavors and three Calculator.java files each for 'main', 'demo' and 'full'.

I want to use

- demo/java/Calculator.java file for demo flavor
- full/java/Calculator.java file for full flavor

while not removing Cacluator.java in main/java directory.

```
android {
    ...
    flavorDimensions 'mode'
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            dimension 'mode'
        }
        full {
            dimension 'mode'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main { java.filter.exclude('Calculator.java') }
        demo {}
        full {}
    }
}
```

[Looks duplicated: Calculator.java files but compiled well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJrPm.png)

[Warning: Duplicated classes found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQPPw.png)

'Duplicated classes found' IDE warning occurs for Calculator.java.
But this project is compiled well.

How can I exclude specific files from indexing in Android Studio?

Can I use 'idea' plugin to resolve this problem?